# Recreate youtube draggable layout

Tags: java, android, youtube

Hello Stackoverflow's users,
I'm trying to recreate a feature of the youtube app that I really like. All I managed to do is find this library that is now deprecated: https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel .You can see the feature I'm talking about here I mean here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12x2seMWgjaDdQ0QHi0lqI_kzWPrtrYHw